# Why does VS Code not allow me to use for each loops or declare arrays properly in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I recently downloaded VS Code on a Mac and installed the C++ extension. For some reason, when I declare

```
    int arr[]{ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 };
```

in my main, as I always have, I get the error

> error: definition of variable with array type needs an explicit size or an initializer

followed by

> error: expected ';' at end of declaration

The exact same code runs on my VS Code on Windows. Does anyone know the problem I am having? For each loops also strangely do not work.

Comment: Use `int arr[] = { ...` -- probably the compiler being used does not support C++11 initializers.  Given that it sounds like range-based loops are also not working, I'd say you are trying to target a C++11 compiler, but the compiler being used by VS Code does not support it.  Maybe there's a switch you can use to enable that language standard, or use a different compiler.

Comment: You don't set the standard in your build step and the default standard of your compiler is used. On Windows usually the default standard is C++11 or C++17. On Mac the default standard is C++03. How do you build your project?

Comment: @paddy VSC des not have a C++ compiler nor does the C++ extension, the user chooses the compiler and modifies `tasks.json` and `launch.json` to use the chosen compiler and debugger

Comment: @ThomasSablik Thanks a lot for the reply. This made me realize the problem. The file complies with no issues if I include `--std=c++11` when compiling. I guess it was defaulting to C++03 as you said. My issue now is with IntelliSense. It is highlighting the "errors" that I mentioned that are compiling and running fine.

Comment: You have to set the standard for IntelliSense: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference. The property is  `cppStandard`